# Two pimcore instances with a document that is used as site won't resolve

Tags: url, zend-framework, pimcore

I have two pimcore instances that are synchronized via MySQL-dump. So they are 1:1 the same.
One is running on an internal server behind our company's firewall, the other one is on a webserver.

Now I'm facing a strange behavior when it comes to a document that is used as a site: the URL won't resolve (`ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`).
The subdomain is existing and it has worked before the second server came into play.

I've tried to fix this via the URL-Helper and via the Frontend-Tool and via several Zend-Controllers but I still get nothing and I'm not even sure if this is a coding- or a server-issue...

Has anyone ever had a similar situation?

Comment: It sounds like DNS error rather than Pimcore / ZF. Are you having same problem in other browsers? Is you request reaching the server (see server access logs).

Comment: Synchronizing the DB might not suffice. Pimcore relies heavily on a lot of dynamically written files. But regarding the original question: M.M. is right - it sounds like a DNS Problem.

Comment: It was working until I started the sync. Since then I don't receive any hits in both /var/log/httpd/access_log. I'm going to flush all caches again - I too start to think this is a DNS-issue. Thanks!

Comment: @chluehr Yes, you're right. But I only need all the object-related stuff synced and this was the fastest solution. I know it's ugly :)

Comment: Even though it can be DNS issue, it's mandatory to clean pimore's cache after DB synchronization.